# Compile TypeScript with modules and bundle to one file

Tags: build, typescript

When using a `module` inside `tsconfig.json` the TypeScript compiler will ignore any `--out` flags and generate regular output, e.g. `commonjs` modules in seperate files.

Is there a way to bundle all transpiled files into a single file?

I am currently trying to use webpack but can not get any of the loaders to run. Running the TypeScript compiler directly works.

Answer (score 0):

For typescript external module bundles you can use the npm package [TsProject](http://www.npmjs.com/package/tsproject)

Comment: Thanks, that module looks very interesting. I am currently just using jspm to bundle everything, which works rather well.
I have a question about `TsProject` do I have to reference all files that need to be bundled?

Comment: TsProject uses the tsconfig.json project file for the project source files compilation context. Essentially all the files in the project are compiled in the first phase. If you supply a "bundles" section in tsconfig.json, each bundle is constructed from a list of files ( blobs, etc. ). Each "bundle" file is then scanned ( the typescript "nodes" generated in the first phase ) for external source module file dependencies with a bundle typescript file created. The bundle file is then compiled with a js and d.ts file created.