# TypeScript bundling not working for External Modules

Tags: module, typescript, amd, bundling-and-minification, tsc

I've a sample TypeScript code and I'm trying to **bundle** multiple **ts/tsx** files using **typescript compiler (tsc)**.

Here is the code:

**File: ISample.ts**

```
    class ISample{
        constructor(public value:string){
        }
    }
    export = ISample;
```

**File: Sample.ts**

```
    import ISample = require('./ISample');

    class SampleImpl{
        value: ISample;
        constructor(sample:number){
            this.value = new ISample(sample+'');
        }
    }
```

**File: tsconfig.json**

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "amd",
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "removeComments": true,
            "preserveConstEnums": true,
            "jsx": "react",
            "outFile": "./dist/bundle.js",
            "target": "es3",
            "listFiles": true,
            "sourceMap": false
        },
        "files": [
            "./src/Sample.ts",
            "./src/ISample.ts"
        ]
    }
```

When I run the command:

```
    tsc
```

**bundle.js** is generated but it is completely blank.

**Observations:**

1. The problem doesn't occur when I move the code to **Internal Modules**
2. The problem also doesn't occur when I omit the **import/require** statement and use a declaration for **ISample** class, but in that case **bundle.js** does not contain the code of **ISample** class

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719064/compile-typescript-with-modules-and-bundle-to-one-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported for now: [Suggestion: multi-file external modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17).

There are a set of workarounds, e.g. [Compile TypeScript with modules and bundle to one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719064/compile-typescript-with-modules-and-bundle-to-one-file)

Comment: Thank you @TSV, I didn't know this scenario is not supported by TypeScript compiler. I'm working with webpack currently, which I wanted to drop. I'll stick with webpack for now, since [typescript simple-loader](https://github.com/blakeembrey/typescript-simple-loader) is already doing the job for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @GaganJakhotiya, If this was helpful, could you mark this as as answer?